# it doesnt print out the things i wanted to print

Tags: python

i did whatever i can did but it deosnt print the thing i want but it just come out 
"E Ticketing Automation System
Numbers of adult: 3
Numbers of kids: 3
Numbers of elderly: 3
what kind of membership 1 for corporate  or 2 for family: 1
there is information inputted incorrectly pls re-enter the info above.

Process finished with exit code 0"

```
print("E Ticketing Automation System")

#a for adult b for kids and c for elderly
a = int(input("Numbers of adult: "))
b = int(input("Numbers of kids: "))
c = int(input("Numbers of elderly: "))
membership = input("what kind of membership 1 for corporate  or 2 for 
family: ")

totalprice = (a*10.00) + (b*7.50) + (c*5.50)
kiddo=b*7.50


corporate = totalprice-(totalprice/100)*20
ccorporate=(totalprice/100)*20
family = totalprice-(b*7.50)


if membership == 1:
   print("The original price before discount is $,",totalprice,"after 20 
   percent discount",ccorporate, "the total price will be $",corporate, )
elif membership == 2:
   print("The original price is $",totalprice,"but after deduction of the 
   kids price $",kiddo,"the total price will be $",family,)
else:
   print("there is information inputted incorrectly pls re-enter the info 
   above.")
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be casting `membership` to an int like you do with your other input?

Comment: It’s better to compare `membership`to `'1'` (as a string) as this will avoid ValueError when you call `int()`

Comment: hi there is new error i met i posted right below the ans

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to consider the input for the variable `membership` as `int`.

Here is the updated source code,

```
print("E Ticketing Automation System")

#a for adult b for kids and c for elderly
a = int(input("Numbers of adult: "))
b = int(input("Numbers of kids: "))
c = int(input("Numbers of elderly: "))
membership = int(input("what kind of membership 1 for corporate  or 2 for family: "))

totalprice = (a*10.00) + (b*7.50) + (c*5.50)
kiddo=b*7.50


corporate = totalprice-(totalprice/100)*20
ccorporate=(totalprice/100)*20
family = totalprice-(b*7.50)


if membership == 1:
   print("The original price before discount is $,",totalprice,"after 20 percent discount",ccorporate, "the total price will be $",corporate, )
elif membership == 2:
   print("The original price is $",totalprice,"but after deduction of the kids price $",kiddo,"the total price will be $",family,)
else:
   print("there is information inputted incorrectly pls re-enter the info above.")
```

Expected output :

```
E Ticketing Automation System
Numbers of adult: 3
Numbers of kids: 3
Numbers of elderly: 3
what kind of membership 1 for corporate  or 2 for family: 1
The original price before discount is $, 69.0 after 20 percent discount 13.799999999999999 the total price will be $ 55.2
```